# High CPU usage in whm without any real user

Tags: cpu

I'm experiencing high CPU usage on one of my cPanel-hosted websites despite having no active users according to Google Analytics. When checking with 'htop' in the shell, I noticed that the process 'lsphp' is consuming a lot of CPU resources, specifically linked to the file '/home/username/public_html/product/index.php'. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

CSF configurations have been set up, I'm even under attack mode in Cloudflare is active. How can I precisely determine the source of these requests? Is it an attack or is there an issue with the website files? (Of course, the website files haven't been modified.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63496078/php-what-is-lsphp might be worth a read, first.

Comment: You should be able to see what's going on with site traffic by looking at your web server `access_log`. There's a lot of things it could be, but without more information it's hard to tell. Is the server sized correctly for the amount of traffic? Is the PHP code optimised? Is there a large amount of data being processed? Large images being served? Many open connections? It's not super straightforward to debug this without more information.